# Replace a block of code with another

Tags: replace

How can I replace a block of code with another, akin to `query-replace`/`query-replace-regexp`?

For example:

Replacing the following block:

```
for(A) {
  if(B) {
     s1;
  } else {
     C;
  }
}
```

with

```
for(M) {
  if(N) {
    s1;
  } else {
     O;
  }
}
```

Comment: You just run `query-replace`? What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [iedit](https://github.com/victorhge/iedit) for that.

[image]
image source: [iedit github repository](https://github.com/victorhge/iedit)

You should select your block of code and activate `iedit-mode` (`C-;`) to edit it.

> When Iedit mode is turned on, all the occurrences of the current
>   region in the buffer (possibly narrowed) or a region are highlighted. 
>   If one occurrence is modified, the change are propagated to all other
>   occurrences simultaneously.
>
> If region is not active, ‘iedit-default-occurrence’ is called to get
>   an occurrence candidate, according to the thing at point.  It might be
>   url, email address, markup tag or current symbol(or word).
>
> In the above two situations, with digit prefix argument 0, only
>   occurrences in current function are matched.  This is good for
>   renaming refactoring in programming.

After install `iedit-mode` from MELPA, I encourage you to read the full help (`C-h f` `iedit-mode`).

Comment: Seems neat. Would check it out. Also, what are you using make the screencasts and displaying the keyboard input?

Comment: This gif is not mine, it is from iedit github repo.
He used probably `command-log-mode` (`C-c o` to show/hide the log);
for screencast you could search for "screencast" on `list-packages`.
If you have different questions you should ask them in new questions
so others can find them.

Answer (score 0):

The `query-replace-regexp` does the job.

[image: <code>query-replace-regexp</code> demo:]

Comment: Can you elaborate? Perhaps show or explain how it "does the job".